# Kotlin(Android) MD5 checking with PHP Signature

Tags: php, android, ios, kotlin, hash

I been working on this for days.

Our backend have a signature checking which is done using PHP:

```php
private $HMAC_ALGO = 'md5';

public function decodeAndValidateMessage($data,$signature,$secretkey) {
    if (!is_string($data)) {
      throw new InvalidRequestException($data);
    }

    $decodedData = base64_decode($data);

    // if not json returned the throw exception...
    $jsonDecoded = json_decode($decodedData,true);
    if (!$jsonDecoded) {
      throw new InvalidRequestException($decodedData);
    }

    // validate
    $signatureRef = base64_encode(hash_hmac($this->HMAC_ALGO,$decodedData,$secretkey,true));
    if ($signature === $signatureRef) {
      return $jsonDecoded;
    } else {
      throw new InvalidSignatureException();
    }
}
```

I made it work on iOS:

```swift
func hmac(_ algorithm: HMACAlgorithm, key: String) -> String {
    let cKey = key.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let cData = self.cString(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    var result = [CUnsignedChar](repeating: 0, count: Int(algorithm.digestLength()))
    CCHmac(algorithm.toCCHmacAlgorithm(), cKey!, Int(strlen(cKey!)), cData!, Int(strlen(cData!)), &result)
    let hmacData:Data = Data(bytes: UnsafePointer<UInt8>(result), count: (Int(algorithm.digestLength())))
    let hmacBase64 = hmacData.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
    print(String(hmacBase64))
    return String(hmacBase64)
}
```

Any idea/help on doing this on Kotlin/Android? I'm being stuck on `InvalidSignatureException` error.

```
fun generateSignature(data : HashMap<String, Any>) : String {
    val hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5")
    hmac.init(SecretKeySpec(Constant.PRIVATEKEY.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), hmac.algorithm))
    return Base64.encodeToString(data.toString().toByteArray(),Base64.URL_SAFE + Base64.NO_PADDING + Base64.NO_CLOSE + Base64.NO_WRAP)
}
```

Thanks :D I really appreciate for any help :D

**Update:**

Just to make my question simpler?

Is it possible to make translate the iOS line of code to Kotlin?

enum HMACAlgorithm {

```
case md5, sha1, sha224, sha256, sha384, sha512

func toCCHmacAlgorithm() -> CCHmacAlgorithm {
    var result: Int = 0
    switch self {
    case .md5:
        result = kCCHmacAlgMD5
    case .sha1:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA1
    case .sha224:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA224
    case .sha256:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA256
    case .sha384:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA384
    case .sha512:
        result = kCCHmacAlgSHA512
    }
    return CCHmacAlgorithm(result)
}

func digestLength() -> Int {
    var result: CInt = 0
    switch self {
    case .md5:
        result = CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .sha1:
        result = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .sha224:
        result = CC_SHA224_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .sha256:
        result = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .sha384:
        result = CC_SHA384_DIGEST_LENGTH
    case .sha512:
        result = CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH
    }
    return Int(result)
}
```

}

this is how I call the function

var params : Dictionary

params.generateSignature()

Comment: Can you provide more details about the error ? Maybe a backtrace and some data samples passed to the function with their respective expected results. It will help people targeting the origin of the error.

Comment: Hello @DamienFlament I cannot give the data it contains sensitve data...

Comment: @DamienFlament. Lets just say that the hashmap is a json string also with iOS

Comment: $signatureRef = base64_encode(hash_hmac($this->HMAC_ALGO,$decodedData,$secretkey,true));
    if ($signature === $signatureRef) {
      return $jsonDecoded;
    } else {
      throw new InvalidSignatureException();
    }

Comment: this is the source of the error. it seems that md5 from android/kotlin is not the same

Comment: MD5 and HMAC are age old algorithms. You're making some kind of mistake, but please show the full stack trace and the line where it occurs. If you have exceptions like these, then at least perform a single statement per line for debugging.

Comment: @MrDeveloper Please provide the details by editing your question. Formatting in comments is not suitable for source code. Please provide error messages and the related code. It may save people running the code to reproduce the error.

Comment: ok thanks..will edit my question

Answer (score -1):

fun generateSignature(data : HashMap) : String {
    val hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacMD5")
    hmac.init(SecretKeySpec(Constant.PRIVATEKEY.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), hmac.algorithm))
    return Base64.encodeToString(data.toString().toByteArray(),Base64.URL_SAFE + Base64.NO_PADDING + Base64.NO_CLOSE + Base64.NO_WRAP)
}

Someone finally found out the answer.

My mistake is hashmap should be run under JSONObject

var obj = JsonObject(data)

and use obj.toString() :D